# Sample writing a generic object to Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

Suppose i have multiple entities that inherit from  TableEntity.

i want to use a generic class , like Cachemanager , and write to azure storage different T

This link below mentions TableEntityAdapter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentityadapter-1.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet

I am looking for a Code examples. 
Thanks,Peter

Answer (score 6):

I wrote TableEntityAdapter class so I will try to provide usage example, though I see question is asked a month ago, hopefully it is still usefull.

Firstly have a look at how it is tested by the unit tests by the SDK: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Test/ClassLibraryCommon/Table/TableOperationUnitTests.cs

search for TableEntityAdapter to find relevant tests.. Note that unit tests of course do not write to actual table Storage service, they simulate what would happen when you read and write in terms of api calls, but they should give you a good idea.

Your original ShapeEntity object does not even need to implement ITableEntity interface. It also can contain complex nested properties. `TableEntityAdapter` class supports these scenarios.

Below is a simplified sample code for `TableEntityAdapter`:

To write your custom .Net object to Table Storage:

```
      // 1. ShapeEntity is the custom .Net object that we want to write and read from Table Storage.
            ShapeEntity shapeEntity = new ShapeEntity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "square", 4, 4);

            OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext();
    // 2. Instantiate a TableEntityAdapter object, passing in the custom object to its constructor. Internally this instance will keep a reference to our custom ShapeEntity object. 

            TableEntityAdapter<ShapeEntity> writeToTableStorage = new TableEntityAdapter<ShapeEntity>(shapeEntity, partitionKey, rowKey);

// 3. Now you can write the writeToTableStorage object to Table Storage just like any other object which inherits from ITableEntity interface. The TableAdapter generic class handles the boiler plate code and hand shaking between your custom .Net object and table storage sdk / service.

To read your custom object from Table Storage:

// 1. Read your entity back from table storage using the same partition / row key you specified (see step 2 above). You can use the Retrieve<T> table operation, specify T as TableEntityAdapter<ShapeEntity>

// 2. This should return you the TableEntityAdapter<ShapeEntity> object that you wrote to TableStorage at step 3 above.

// 3. To access the original ShapeEntity object, just refer to the OriginalEntity property of the returned TableEntityAdapter<ShapeEntity> object.
```

Your original ShapeEntity object does not even need to implement ITableEntity interface. It also can contain complex nested properties. TableEntityAdapter class supports these scenarios.

**Note:** `TableEntityAdapter` api does not support objects with collection type properties ie. `List`, `Array`, `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` etc..

If your objects contain these types of properties (directly under the root or somewhere in their object graph) then you should consider using the original Nuget package that I wrote which supports collection type property types as well.

`ObjectFlattenerRecomposer` Api version 2.0 that supports Collection, Enumerable type properties:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

and recently uploaded .Net Core version:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer.Core/1.0.0/