# Best practice of using TableEntity (Azure table storage) - decoupling of classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, azure-storage, blazor

I'm prototyping right now on a bigger project and need to make some design decisions..

My VS Solution consists (for now, might separate it further later) of 4 projects:

- A .NET Standard 2.1 project with all my entities (e.g. a Customer class), containing mostly simple properties, but some also contains enumerations and lists. I want this be simple with no dependencies.
- A Web project using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Blazor WebAssembly (client-side only)
- An Application project containing the infrastructure and services (e.g. this is where `AzureTableStorage<T>` resides)
- An Azure Function layer that is the 'mediator' between web and application, which depends on Application layer (injects the CustomerService)

For storage I'm using Azure storage table, and my problem is to find an elegant decoupled way of implementing this.

I'm using this example more or less: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-page-application-in-blazor-with-azure-table-storage/ for CRUD operations to the tables.

But in order to use this I'm relying on inheriting `TableEntity`, which is annoying. Also my WebUI is using Blazor, so it takes in a bunch of Azure Cosmos dll to the browser that is not needed if I choose to inherit `TableEntity`.

So I can't decide if I just need to pursue decoupling my poco classes and get rid `TableEntity`.. I saw something about using `TableEntityAdapter`, but can't find any example using it?

Another approach might be to have Dto "duplicate" classes of my POCO classes, which then could inherit the TableEntity. But then I would need to maintain these classes. But might be needed since I don't think the methods in Azure Storage library can handle lists, enumeration etc. out of the box. But then again if I can make some generic adapter that takes care of more complex types, a Dto class could be redundant.

Looking for input and inspiration basically :)

Thanks

Comment: "Dto 'duplicate' classes of my POCO classes" are called DAO's (Data Access Objects). It would be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, but I'm already using a repository pattern (from example - check PersonService.cs)), and it seems like DAO's contain Get, Update, Create methods as well, so seems like same-same. E.g. PersonService(IAzureTableStorage < Person > repository) in which Person is the POCO class that needs to inherit from TableEntity (that I want to get rid of)

Comment: NO, a DAO ususally doesn't contain any methods orlogic (except maybe some for conversion/formatting). CRUD methods belong in a Repository.

Comment: Ok found this blogpost, where he creates a dynamic dto (guess it's equivalent to DAO), that converts Poco to dto on the fly. Seems like a lot of work though, I was hoping the TableEntity adapter could help out 
 https://bretthargreaves.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/azure-table-storage-with-repository-pattern/

Comment: Ok seems like I just pass in TableEntityAdapter<MyEntityClass>(myEntitity> to the repository which inherits TableEntity. I will pursue that for now.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044207/sample-writing-a-generic-object-to-azure-storage

Comment: My understanding is that it will be problematic when MyEntityClass has complex or nav properties. But I'd like to hear your results. Note that you can add a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have now worked out an approach. I'll share it here.

The thing is that you can either dennormalize the table, aka. make the entities with all its nested objects and list properties into 1 tableentity => 1 row. This implies that complex properties or classtype properties needs to be serialized into strings (json most likely).

Or you can make relationships, where the entities are sharing the same partitionkey. Then create them in batch. E.g. Department -> Persons. So a Department has partionkey = Department01 and Person X has partionkey = Department01. 2 rows.

But what if you actually want to do both, say have different rows, but each tableentity also has IEnumerable properties like lists and collections that would be overkill to separate into different rows aswell.

I found this great community library that I expanded on and made 2 generic methods. They are not perfect, but it's a start.

https://github.com/giometrix/TableStorage.Abstractions.POCO

Here you can easily convert a POCO entity into a TableEntity and vice versa, aka. denormalizing.

I added these 2 generic methods to the library:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Adds relationship One To Many between source (one) and related entitiy targets (many). Source and related targets have seperate rows but share the same partition key
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TTarget">Target class, ex. Persons</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entitySource">Source entity that only has one entry</param>
    /// <param name="relatedEntities">Related entities contained in source entity, this can be 0 to many, ex. e => e.Persons</param>
    /// <param name="entityTargetRowKey">Target entity rowkey property, needs to be different than source rowkey</param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    public async Task InsertBatchOneToMany<TTarget>(T entitySource, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TTarget>>> relatedEntities, Expression<Func<TTarget, string>> entityTargetRowKey)  where TTarget : class
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: Put related property on ignorelist for json serializing

            //Create the batch operation
            TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

            IEnumerable<TTarget> targets = relatedEntities.Compile().Invoke(entitySource);

            //Insert source entity to batch
            DynamicTableEntity source = CreateEntity(entitySource);
            batchOperation.InsertOrMerge(source);

            //Insert target entities to batch
            foreach (var entityTarget in targets)
            {
                string trowKey = entityTargetRowKey.Compile().Invoke(entityTarget);
                batchOperation.InsertOrMerge(entityTarget.ToTableEntity(source.PartitionKey, trowKey));
            }

            //Execute batch
            IList<TableResult> results = await _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            throw new StorageException($"Error saving data to Table." +
                $"{ System.Environment.NewLine}Error Message: {ex.Message}" +
                $"{ System.Environment.NewLine}Error Extended Information: {ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage}" +
                $"{ System.Environment.NewLine}Error Code: {ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve source and its related target entities back again to source
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TTarget">Related Entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="partitionKey">Partionkey shared by source and related target entities</param>
    /// <param name="relatedEntities">Related entities contained in source entity, ex. e => e.Persons</param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    public async Task<T> GetBatchOneToMany<TTarget>(string partitionKey, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TTarget>>> relatedEntities) where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        var dynTableEntities = await _tableStore.GetByPartitionKeyAsync(partitionKey);

        T convertSource = new T();
        TTarget convertTarget = new TTarget();

        var targetObjects = new List<TTarget>();
        MemberExpression member = relatedEntities.Body as MemberExpression;
        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        IEnumerable<TTarget> targets = relatedEntities.Compile().Invoke(convertSource);

        bool sourceFound = false;
        foreach (var dynTableEntity in dynTableEntities)
        {
            //Try convert to source
            int nonNullValuesSource = 0;
            int nonNullValuesTarget = 0;
            if (!sourceFound)
            {
                convertSource = dynTableEntity.FromTableEntity<T>();
                nonNullValuesSource = convertSource.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(convertSource)).Count(v => v != null);
            }
            //Try convert to target
            convertTarget = dynTableEntity.FromTableEntity<TTarget>();
            nonNullValuesTarget = convertTarget.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(convertTarget)).Count(v => v != null);

            if (nonNullValuesSource > nonNullValuesTarget)
            {
                sourceFound = true;
            }
            else
            {
                targetObjects.Add(convertTarget);
            }
        }

        propInfo.SetValue(convertSource, targetObjects);
        return convertSource;

    }
```

This allows me to make relationships and denormalize the rows at the same time.

Usage:

```
 public async Task AddProject(GovernorProject project)
    {

        //Commit to table
        await _repository.InsertBatchOneToMany(project, p => p.Environments, e => e.DisplayName);
    }


public async Task<GovernorProject> GetProject(string projectId)
    {
        return await _repository.GetBatchOneToMany(projectId, p => p.Environments);

    }
```

In my case here, I have a main entity of a Project and each project have 0 or more Environments related which is held on a `Collection<Environment> Environment` property on the GovernorProject